# Switch js style.css code to jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I wrote a javascript function that shrinks my header and moves some elements when the user scrolls by adding css.  Works great but not all changes are smooth (even though original css has `transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out`).  So now I want to use the jquery `animate()` or `switchClass()` but when I try to change the code to jquery, it doesn't work.  There is no error in the console, it just does nothing on scroll.

This is the working javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  var mqtab = window.matchMedia("(min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1023px)");
  var mqdesk = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    if (mqdesk.matches) {
      document.getElementById("homelink").style.cssText = "width: 15%; margin-left: 5%";
      document.getElementById("menuWrapper").style.cssText = "margin-top: 0; position: absolute; right: 5%; bottom: 0";
      document.getElementById("menu").style.cssText = "font-size: .9em; line-height: 1.52em; margin-top: 1px";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("homelink").style.cssText = "width: 60%; margin: auto";
    document.getElementById("menuWrapper").style.cssText = "margin-top: 20px; position: relative";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.cssText = "font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.65em; margin-top: 0";
  }
}
```

This is my attempt at changing some of it to jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  scrollFunction();
});

function scrollFunction() {
  var mqtab = window.matchMedia("(min-width:769px) and (max-width: 1023px)");
  var mqdesk = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    if (mqdesk.matches) {
      $("homelink").animate({width: "15%", "margin-left": "5%"});
      $("menuWrapper").animate({"margin-top": "0", "position": "absolute", "right": "5%", "bottom": "0"});
      $("menu").animate({"font-size": ".9em", "line-height": "1.52em", "margin-top": "1px"});
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("homelink").style.cssText = "width: 60%; margin: auto";
    document.getElementById("menuWrapper").style.cssText = "margin-top: 20px; position: relative";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.cssText = "font-size: 1em; line-height: 1.65em; margin-top: 0";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some HTML.

Comment: @ikiK The HTML is meaningless.  The code works as javascript.  My issue is with the conversion to jQuery.  I don't understand the rules for jQuery and so there must be something wrong with my syntax or something but there is no error in console so I don't know what.